# main.bundle.js too big in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, webpack, bundle

I have bundled my main page using webpack , but the problem the file is too big and takes 1min to open my app.

I wonder if there is any helpful plugin to minimize the size of the bundle file !
[image]

webpack.common.js

```js
"use strict";

const path = require("path");
const autoprefixer = require("autoprefixer");
const postcssFlexbugsFixes = require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

const extractSassBundle = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "[name].bundle.css",
});

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    feeds: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/_feeds/index.js"),
    main: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/_main/index.js"),
    admin: path.resolve(__dirname, "src/_admin/index.js"),
  },
  plugins: [extractSassBundle],
  resolve: {
    extensions: [".js", ".jsx"],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: [/\.js$/, /\.jsx?$/],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
      },
    
    
    
     
    ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    path: path.join(__dirname, "/public/build"),
    publicPath: "/",
  },
};
```

Please share with my your ideas to solve this problem.

Comment: Is Ko == Kb? If yes, there is no reason for 2mins to download 4Mb. Maybe a long request inside the app

Comment: Ko == Kb ? what doest that mean

Comment: In your image, the size is read as Ko